# Time Synch Issue in Win Server OS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, time-synchronization, w32time

There is time sync issue in couple of server's. Below is the Description

There are two identical server's with same OS and same set of software's running. And they are pretty new server's.In every 30 Min or so OS time gets changed to some random time. There is no chance of CMOS battery going bad. As these are new we even replaced the motherboard.

I ran the `W32tm /query /status` command in two of the server's and below is what i see.

Source in two server differ and also Stratum: 1 (primary reference - syncd by radio clock) and ReferenceId: 0x4C4F434C (source name: "LOCL").

How do i get the Problematic server running with correct time.

**Server with No Problem: Server:1**

```
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning) 
Stratum: 1 (primary reference - syncd by radio clock)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0000000s
Root Dispersion: 10.0000000s 
ReferenceId: 0x4C4F434C (source name: "LOCL") 
Last Successful Sync Time: 8/9/2016 8:49:46 AM
Source: Local CMOS
Clock Poll Interval: 10 (1024s)
```

**Server with Problem: Server:2**

```
Leap Indicator: 3(last minute has 61 seconds)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified) 
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0000000s Root 
Dispersion: 0.0000000s 
ReferenceId: 0x00000000 (unspecified)
Last Successful Sync Time: unspecified
Source: Free-running
System Clock Poll Interval: 10 (1024s)
```

Comment: Since you changed the motherboard, is it safe to assume neither of those are VMs? Are the servers in a domain or even domain controllers?

Comment: If the servers are not in a domain, [try to re-configure time services](http://serverfault.com/questions/604496/is-timesync-still-required-for-windows-server-2012-r2/605551#605551). Does the problem persist afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:DOMHIER  
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

Comment: This answer only works from servers and computers that are members of an active-directory domain. (Greg, I know that you know that. )

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`NetTime`](http://www.timesynctool.com/) to configure automatic SNTP clock synchronization. It is very fast and very reliable.

Comment: Why install a third-party software, when the built-in time server is perfectly fine?

Comment: If it has problem running w32tm and need a quick and reliable solution, NetTime is the perfect one. It is very precise and reliable. Moreover, while w32tm has its big share of quirks, NetTime always worked at first try.

Comment: Fair enough. I never encountered any quirks and I strongly believe that a properly configured w32tm-service is just as reliable. My opinion on those kind of problems are that they were either misconfigured in the first place, or configured without understanding the parameters that were passed to the executable. I always think of 'quick solutions' like NetTime that the admin is too lazy to read the documentation. And if the server resets the time every 30 minutes, that won't change with NetTime, it will just cover up the underlying issue. This is my personal opinion only.

Answer (score -2):

If you are running hyper-v and hosting a domain controller, that will cause all sorts of time drift.  I found that if I run [nistime32.exe[1](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/its.cfm) on the physical hyper-v machine, it solves my time drift problem.  I recommend creating a scheduled task that runs every hour to solve the problem.